# Authetication from 3rd Party Application to Host iFrames

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an application that hosts a series of iFrames within a 3rd party application. How can I assure only the 3rd party application will have access to my application and prevent any outside parties from accessing my application?

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: Once take the `iframes` path you are doomed to follow it until you fall into the abyss. And start your design from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 3rd party web application gives us no choice, but to follow this design.